# Pulling entry from MySQLdb in Python

Tags: python, mysql, select, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use Python to connect to a MySQL db, query for the value of one field and return if it matches a predefined value.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tablename")
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    for row in rows:
        print row
```

This is what I have so far and it is returning a value similar to (0L, usernamefield, passwordfield, field3).  How can I add to this code so that I can specify to pull the entry WHERE user = "therightuser" AND pass = "therightpass" and then from tha entry pull the value of field3.  Something similar to...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table name WHERE user ='therightuser' AND pass ='therightpass'")
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    for row in rows:
        print row[field3]
    if field3 == "yes":
            print ("The field says yes")
    else:
            print ("The field says no")
```

Comment: It's `WHERE`, not `WHEN`

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs Thanks. Any idea on how to parse the query?

Comment: What you have *should* work although it doesn't make much sense. If you're going to `fetchone()` then there's no need for a loop. Either `fetchall()` and loop or `fetchone()` and access the value directly. And I never used `mysqldb` but you may have to do `row[3]` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table name WHERE user ='therightuser' AND pass ='therightpass'")
    row = cur.fetchone()
    print row[3]
    if field3 == "yes":
            print ("The field says yes")
    else:
            print ("The field says no")
```

Alternatively, a safer implementation would be:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM table name WHERE user=%s AND pass=%s""", ('therightuser', 'therightpass'))
```

And if you would like to be able to access the data by the column name, i.e. as
`print row['field3']`, you can use the following method:

```
def FetchOneAssoc(cursor) :
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data == None :
        return None
    desc = cursor.description

    dict = {}

    for (name, value) in zip(desc, data) :
        dict[name[0]] = value

    return dict
```

So after your `cur.execute(...)`, you would have:

```
row = FetchOneAssoc(cur)
print row['field3']
```

Reference http://www.ianhowson.com/a-quick-guide-to-using-mysql-in-python.html

Comment: It worked.  Thanks for giving me options also :) Cheers.